# TypeError: mongoclient.db is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Please Someone response me with what's wrong with this code...
When I run the program ,I find the bug in mongodb part.
The error in

```
var db = mongoclient.db();
```

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017), {native_parser: true});

var db = mongoclient.db();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('hello_combined').findOne({}, function(err, doc) {

        if(err) throw err;

        res.render('hello', doc);
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
});

mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: You need to open with `mongoclient.open` before .db

Answer (score 0):

I'm only showing you this code because It shows how to connect to a database.

I didn't need that `Server = require('mongodb').Server;` section that you have.

The code shows how to

1. require monogodb to get the Driver for mongodb in Node. `require("mongodb").MongoClient`
2. then you connect using MongoClient.connect. In my case Im connecting to my allready existing database called `crunchbase`
3. then you can query the database I find the field with the name of `category_code` and the value `biotech` in the collection `companies`.

---

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/crunchbase", function(err, db){
   console.log("connected to the DB");

   var query = {"category_code" : "biotech"};
   db.collection("companies").find(query).toArray(function(err, docs){
       docs.forEach(function(doc){
           console.log(doc.name + " is a " + doc.category_code  + "company")
        });
    db.close()
  })
})
```

Comment: In new Mongo suggestions, only admin can store credentials. So you need to switch for ops to required DB.